# .ie10 and .ie11 class Magento 2

Tags: magento2, css, html

So, I was working on making my webshop IE and Edge ready an stumbled on the following problem in IE: my background would not y-repeat and would only take the height (as it seemed) of the screen. After stackoverflowing my question (because I assumed it was pure a HTML/CSS + IE issue), someone mentioned something about setting the height of my page-wrapper to `auto`. When I did this, it still not worked while it worked for him in IE. So, digging into the code, I saw that Magento created a `.ie10` and `.ie11` class to my `page-wrapper` with only the following style: `height: 100%`. I overwrote the style with `height: auto` and now everything works fine.

My question is: why does this happen in Magento 2 and what is the reason that the style `height: 100%` is applied to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `height: 100%;` was added as Internet Explorer does not honour `min-height` when combined with flexbox, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40490954/flex-container-min-height-ignored-in-ie) for more info on that.

If you don't want to use flexbox it can be disabled by setting the `@use-flex` variable to false in `lib/web/css/source/lib/variables/_responsive.less:10` (copying the file into your theme).

Comment: But the page-wrapper does not have flex assigned to it. I couldn't figure out even if they mean that a child has flex style assigned to it?

Comment: It does, look at `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less:284`. It uses two mixins to apply the flex properties `.lib-vendor-prefix-display(flex);` and `.lib-vendor-prefix-flex-direction(column);`. Or at least in 2.1, I presume it's still there in 2.2. If not then it's likely they left the min-height in by mistake?

Comment: Ah okay, then that would be the problem. I can't blame them, it's just Internet Explorer that sucks so bad.

Comment: Yeah, Magento 2 was initially released with IE9+ support but after [this issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5126) was raised they changed support to IE11+ so the IE10 class is legacy code anyway.